# How prove $ \int_0^1 f(x)dx-\exp\left(\int_0^1\log(f(x)) dx\right)\le\max_{0\le x,y\le 1}\left(\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}\right)^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider a continuous function  $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^{+}$. How show that

$\int_0^1 f(x)dx-\exp\left(\int_0^1 \log(f(x)) dx\right)\le \max_{0\le x,y\le 1}\left(\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}\right)^2$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885622/functional-inequality-with-a-strong-rhs). This link does not have an answer though.

Comment: see leshik's solution with mixing variables [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845355/how-prove-this-stronger-am-gm-inequality-fracn2-16-min-1-le-ij-le-n-le?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

It is the continuous version of a well-known result about the difference between the arithmetic and geometric mean: see, for instance, [the article](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2005294?sid=21104947256191&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3738296) of S. H. Tung, or [the article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00013-012-0434-7#page-1) of J. M. Aldaz, proving that:

> If $0\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq\ldots\leq a_n$ and $X=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$,
>   then: $$ AM(X)-GM(X)\leq n \operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{X}).$$

Comment: Jack san for us who do not have access to jstor contents it will be helpful if you summarized the results of the paper in the answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: @r9m: answer updated :)

Comment: @r9m: You're welcome.

Comment: This is nice! +1.

Comment: This is AMM problem (2014),I have a nice methods

Comment: @math110 the discrete version was Joszef Wildt math competition 2012 problem W-32 :)